# ADF7242 cannot receive packet while trying to get RSSI from driver

Tags: wifi, iot, rssi, imx6, 6lowpan

Dear Stack Overflow community,

I am currently working on a project involving the **802.15.4** protocol and **RFC6551**. I have encountered a particular issue and would like to seek your assistance in resolving it.

Here is a brief overview of the problem:
I have enabled the Register **pkt_cfg** and set the **Field auto_fcs_off to 1** successfully. Additionally, I have been able to read the RSSI value from the Register rrb using the Field rssi_readback.

However, when I attempt to read the RSSI in one of the ADFs while keeping the other ADF in default mode, communication between the devices fails. The receiving ADF does not receive the signal.

In simpler terms, making changes to only one ADF leads to failure, while applying changes to both ADFs allows for successful operation.

Based on my observations, I suspect that the ADF may be transitioning from the compliance level to proprietary mode in terms of the 802.15.4 protocol. However, I am unable to determine the exact cause of this behavior.

If anyone has any suggestions, insights, or potential solutions to address this issue, I would greatly appreciate your assistance.

Thank you for your time and expertise

**What I tried:**
I have attempted to find a solution by referring to the ADF7242 data sheet, but unfortunately, it did not provide any resolution to the issue at hand. Furthermore, my search in online forums yielded information suggesting that both the transmit and receive packets should have the auto_fcs_off set to 1. However, since the register for both transmit and receive is the same, implementing this solution did not resolve the problem.